# accessing pixels[ ] array in p5.js (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

I'm trying to loop through each pixel in the canvas, check and store its colour. If not white, (something happens), else, (nothing).
There will be a nested loop, but I am confused with the 'idx' value, as written in the [reference](http://p5js.org/reference/#p5.Image/pixels[]):

```
var d = pixelDensity;
  for (var i = 0; i < d; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < d; j++) {
      // loop over
      idx = 4*((y * d + j) * width * d + (x * d + i));
      pixels[idx] = r;
      pixels[idx+1] = g;
      pixels[idx+2] = b;
      pixels[idx+3] = a;
    }
  }
```

I guess it has to do with reading pixel matrix using (x,y) but I am not even sure it's necessary. I'm trying to make a target-based particle system, following this [tutorial](http://nullcandy.com/particle-text-in-xna-and-javascript/) that uses text.

help?

Comment: not familiar with p5, but am familiar with pixel arrays. the example code seems to be missing the definition of the x/y value. usually idx represents the index of the pixel when converting from a 2d matrix (the image, 4 byte pixel per height per width) in a 1 dimensional array. shouldn't there be a double loop for height/width instead of pixel density?

Comment: looking at it again, it might be living inside the height/width loop (so you get 4 nested loops), to account for pixel density?

Answer (score 1):

This is my calculation:

index = 4 * ((this.y0 + j) * this.W + this.x0 + i)

Not sure about your pixeldensity.
You are also squaring it.

I have noticed different behaviour on Windows and (ios+linux)

My code works on Windows only.